# Eagle: Removing unwanted bits of copper pour

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, copper-pour

I have lazily made a copper pour in Eagle by highlighting a rectangle around my irregular shaped board. How do I then selectively remove the copper pour from outside the board boundary and the little unconnected pointless bits between some components?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uncheck the **orphans** property of the polygon.

From Eagle's General Help:

> Orphans
>
> As a polygon automatically keeps a certain distance to other
>   signals it can happen that the polygon is separated into a number of
>   smaller polygons. If such a polygon has no electrical connection to
>   any other (non-polygon) object of its signal, the user might want it
>   to disappear. With the parameter Orphans = Off [default] these
>   isolated zones will disappear. With Orphans = On they will remain. If
>   a signal consists only of polygons and has no other electrically
>   connected objects, all polygon parts will remain, independent of the
>   setting of the Orphans parameter.

Comment: POUR-FECT! Ouch!

Comment: @learnvst ha-chachacha!

Answer (score 3):

Either:

(1) you have not named your copper pour in correspondence to some signal in your schematic (typically GND), or

(2) your board outline is not part of the Dimension layer, or

(3) you drew your polygon using the Rectangle tool rather than the Polygon tool (I simply never use the rectangle tool, I'm not sure what it's appropriate for)

I'm pretty sure Eagle will respect your board perimeter if these rules are adhered to.

Comment: My copper pour is definitely GND and the outline is definitely in the perimeter layer. I drew a rectangle around everything using the polygon tool.

Comment: Are you sure you have a signal named GND in your schematic? type SHOW GND <enter> do those nets you expect become highlighted?

Comment: Yes, those nets are highlighted. Thanks for the `SHOW GND` trick. The key was removing orphans.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the polygon tool to draw an actual polygon using freedrawing. Then. You can go and edit the different vertices of the polygon to make them straight and looking good by changing the x,y locations of the vertices.

Comment: There must be some way to clone the board perimeter, otherwise you'd have to repeat a lot of work to pour a board with an intricately shaped perimeter, no?

Comment: There isn't that I know of. There is no copper pour layer to copy the outline and pour it on, but I do remember the board outline bounding some of the pours. I don't have eagle to check.

Comment: you can draw a rectangle (free-hand) around an arbitrarily shaped perimeter, you don't have to trace the outline